# How to add breadcrumbs on cart page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, shopping-cart, breadcrumbs

I want to add breadcrumbs to the shopping cart page before the page title like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this.?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a file `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

and add following code in **checkout_cart_index.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 6):

Overwrite in ur custom theme `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml` to 
`magento\app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Theme_Name>\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml` & add

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" display="true"> // True/False
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is much better than accepted answer and it resolves my issue.