# Magento2: breadcrumbs are not shown in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

After **adding** this code in **checkout_index_index.xml**  breadcrumbs are not shown.

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Checkout</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Checkout</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Checkout</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

**Note**:same works for **checkout cart** page but not for **checkout page**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare your code with given below code.

IF in theme already have a `checkout_index_index.xml` file then add below code.

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
<action method="addCrumb">
<argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
<argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
<item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
<item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
</argument>
</action>
<action method="addCrumb">
<argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</argument>
<argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
<item name="title" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
<item name="link" xsi:type="string">/checkout/cart</item>
</argument>
</action>
</referenceBlock>
```

In case there is no `checkout_index_index.xml`  file in the layout folder, you have to create new one with such content `(note the file format, it should be .xml):`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
    * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper.grid-container"/>
        <referenceBlock name="page.preloader" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
        <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
        </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
        <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</argument>
        <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Shopping Cart</item>
        <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/checkout/cart</item>
        </argument>
        </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

> Run php bin/magento c:c
>
> Run php bin/magento c:f

Comment: yes checked and not shows

Comment: Find in your whole magento directory is there add code like `<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true">`

Comment: no there is not like this code in any file

Comment: It might be possible this block is override in another file. otherwise it is working form me.

Comment: yes there is custom module where **checkout_index_index** file override but that module was disabled  is that creating issue?

Comment: It might be.. remove `remove="true"` then check

Comment: no i mean not that block was called in that file  just file was overridden

Comment: Just remove that module & check so you can confirm issue related for that or not.

Comment: i delete that file and check but issue is still same

Answer (score 2):

make sure checkout_index_index.xml is in right place app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

in your checkout_index_index.xml file paste below code

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Checkout</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Checkout</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Checkout</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

run this command after adding code **php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush**

if you want also display breadcrubs into checkout shoping cart page follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/174160)

Comment: yes its placed right place  still issue

Comment: make sure your custom app/code directory contains checkout_index_index.xml file? just search around there if yes then add above code there.